# Hotmail sign-in page not drop down listing other email accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

Has Microsoft changed sign-in Hotmail page?

Now have different sign-in page and when I type first letter of email account does not list other accounts I have starting with same first letter.

I am using Outlook on the web.

I have quite a few Hotmail accounts which of course I did not make a note of as I relied on the automatic listing.

Is there a procedure for reinstating the drop down listing?

Comment: Please try and use some punctuation in your questions.

Comment: Question was clear without punctuation.  Did so to minimise details.

Comment: @ianmac Which web browser do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I have several accounts as well and the no drop down is definitely a pain. It is spotty but sometimes the address pops up when you type the first letter which you can then click on. I did find by accident that if you type the first letter or two and the email address does not pop up automatically, just click on 'sign in', it will obviously be an error and the name and password boxes go red, but if you then double click on the partial email address, the full address will then pop up. A bit of a pain and should be better from msn... but saves having to type numerous addresses and remember passwords